# Identifying Ajax request from codeigniter in case of angularjs request

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am using angularjs to send request to my codeigniter controller. I have tested different possibilities like

`$this->input->is_ajax_request()` and a custom made function

```
function is_ajax(){
  $is_ajax = false;
  if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
    $is_ajax = true;
  }
  return $is_ajax;
}
```

Both are not working.

My ajax request code is

```
var f = {};
        $scope.f = f;  

$scope.saveForm = function () {
        $scope.Error = null;
        // Try to login
        $http.post("form", f)
                .then(function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }, function (x) {
                    $scope.Error = 'Server Error';
                });
    }
```

My controller in codeigniter working fine and receiving  request as fine. But I want to filter my Ajax request. What is the solution?

Comment: the angularjs is not sending, or the route in your codeigniter is invalid?

Comment: what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Angular is sending request and Codeigniter can able to receive the request. But I want to identify ajax request as mentioned above

Comment: Is HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH actually showing in $_SERVER when you var_dump?

Comment: Yes I have tested. HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is not in $_SERVER!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http does not include the x-requested-with header by default. You'll need to add it into the $http config when you send your request. Something like this ~should work.

```
$scope.saveForm = function () {
    $scope.Error = null;
    // Try to login
    $http.post("form", f, {
        'headers': { 
            'X-Requested-With' :'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }, function (x) {
        $scope.Error = 'Server Error';
    });
}
```